# Actix web send image as Response

Tags: rust, actix-web

I want to send image to the Frontend with a path /images/{pic_name}.
Here is the actix web way

```
.service(web::resource("/images/{pic_name}").route(web::get().to(images)))
```

And here the fuction images:

```
async fn images(req: HttpRequest, info: web::Path<Info>) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
      Ok(HttpResponse::build(StatusCode::OK)
            .content_type("image/jpeg")
            .body("images/".to_string() + &info.pic_name + &".jpeg"))
}
```

The Folder structure is:

```
images     -| -> inside jpeg and webp
src        -| -> inside the source files rs
Cargo.toml -|
```

My Cargo toml is

```
[dependencies]
actix-web = "4.0.0-beta.5"
actix-service = "2.0.0-beta.5"
actix-files = "0.6.0-beta.8"
actix-rt = "2.4.0"
```

Question: What is the way to send an image like the nodejs on express sendFile way,

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, `/assets/images/${req.params.picName}.${acceptedHeader}`));
```

Edit: maybe the path is wrong or something, cause i get a 200 and always the image is broken.

Comment: _"I get a 200 and always the image is broken"_ That's because you are sending the file path as the actual response, rather than the contents of that file.

Comment: new to Rust here, how could i send the content? Found no basic example about that.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, you are sending the path instead of the file content. First, you should read the content by doing something like this:

```
let image_content = web::block(|| std::fs::read(<your path>)).await?;
```

[`block`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.3.2/actix_web/web/fn.block.html) "execute blocking function on a thread pool, returns future that resolves to result of the function execution." It's needed because -- as far as I know -- [`std::fs::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read.html) is *blocking*.

Then, if you have the content, return it:

```
Ok(HttpResponse::build(StatusCode::OK)
            .content_type("image/jpeg")
            .body(image_content))
```

Comment: your answer is correct, but on actix-web 4 beta there is an error:
the trait `std::convert::From<Result<Vec<u8>, std::io::Error>>` is not implemented for `AnyBody`. I will try to fix that and then check your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That response is only sending the *file path as the body*. You would need to open and read the file to retrieve its contents first, either via standard `std::fs::read`, `tokio_fs::read`, or something else. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70079111) for a possible solution to this.

But with `actix-files`, and assuming that no additional logic is needed, you only need to set up a route to a new static file service.

```rust
use actix_web::App;
use actix_files::Files;

let app = App::new()
    .service(Files::new("/images", "./images"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @Riwen is the correct one, but i was using actix-web 4 beta, so it had errors cause of the changes, solution i used is:

```
let image_content =  actix_web::web::Bytes::from(std::fs::read("src/images/".to_string() + &info.pic_name + ".jpeg")?);
Ok(HttpResponse::build(StatusCode::OK)
.content_type("image/jpeg")
.body(actix_web::dev::AnyBody::Bytes(image_content)))
```

Thas seems to work, but i am new to Rust and no idea if it is a good practice.
P.S. I am not using blocking like the answer from  @Riwen, but still the images are appearing on the frontend. I will comment for more info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The examples above read the data into memory then return the response. For small files that may be OK, however, you should consider using a streaming response instead of something resident in memory. Something like what is demonstrated here using the actix_files crate:

```rust
async fn get_file(filename: web::Path) -> HttpResponse {
    let file_path = std::path::PathBuf::from(env!("HOME"))
        .as_path()
        .join(BASE_DIR)
        .join(DATA_PATH)
        .join(&filename.into_inner());
    
    let file = actix_files::NamedFile::open_async(file_path).await.unwrap();

    file.into_response()
}
```

https://github.com/actix/actix-web/discussions/2720#discussioncomment-2510752